# Automating multiple projects in a solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with 3 different projects A, B and C. Now I have to run the projects in debug mode in the order C, B and A. Is there anyway in which I could automate the running process. Currently I have to run C in debug mode, then B and then A.

Comment: I assume these are all independent projects housed in one solution for convenience?

Comment: Yes they are however they interact with each other during run time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, you can do this by `right-click your solution > Properties > Common Properties > StartUp Project`

Here you can set "Multiple Startup Projects"
[image]

Comment: Missing adequate [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/154460), but +1 anyways.

Comment: @Brad, yes my bad, I have edited answer to include the missing adequate freehand circles. :)